# Guardar archivo txt en una lista y ordenarlo antes de llenar un datagridview

Tags: c#, lista

Necesito ordenar un archivo txt, en el que cada elemento esta separado por comas. Para ordenarlo necesito poner el contenido del archivo en una lista y ordenarlo, para después pasarlo a un datagridview, pero nose muy bien como hacer todo esto.

Estoy trabajando con este código pero puede que no esté yendo por el mejor camino.

```
string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines($@"{Application.StartupPath}\Ventas1.txt");
            var cortar = lineas.Select(linea =>
            {
                string[] partes = linea.Split(',');
                return new { Fecha = partes[0], Codigo = partes[1], Legajo = partes[2], Sucursal = partes[3], Monto = partes[4] };
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ibas mal encaminado, pero la cosa es mas sencilla. Lo que debes hacer es encadenar dos `Select`, uno para el `Split` y otro para generar la lista de la clase anónima:

```
var cortar = lineas
                  .Select(linea => linea.Split(',')) //devuelve un IEnumerable con un array por linea leida
                  .Select(x => new { Fecha = x[0], Codigo = x[1], Legajo = x[2], Sucursal = x[3], Monto = x[4] }) // con cada uno de esos arrays generamos la clase anónima
                  .ToList();
```